# Is it safe to return file File descriptor locally allocated from another function In C

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

FILE * BestTry();

int main()
{
    char arr[] = "hello";
    FILE * desc = BestTry();
    fwrite(arr,1,5,desc);
    fclose(desc);
}

FILE * BestTry()
{
    FILE * retDesc = fopen(".\\hello.dat","w+");
    return retDesc;
}
```

Is it is safe to use `desc` for any use because I am allocating memory to a local variable in function `BestTry`. If it is safe then what is the reason?

Comment: That's a FILE pointer, not a file descriptor such as those returned from an `open` system call for example.

Answer (score 5):

The `FILE` object is *not* local to your `BestTry` function. That function gets a pointer to a `FILE` object, and that pointer is indeed local, but the object itself is not.

What you're doing is fine, the actual `FILE` object is still live when you return the pointer. (Well fine except you're not checking the return values of the system calls, so you'll have an extremely hard time debugging your program when it fails.)

Comment: Yes, and if you write `return fopen(...);` you won't even _have_ a local variable to worry about.

Answer (score 3):

You are returning the value of the file-descriptor and NOT a reference to the local variable itself. This is perfectly safe as the value of a file-descriptor is unique to a process.

> When you open a file, the operating system will creates an entry to represent that file and store the information about that opened file. So if there are N files opened, the there will be N integers, each a file descriptor. They are simply integers that uniquely represents an open file. If your process open 10 files then your Process table will have 10 entries for file descriptors.

---

**Side-note** : The result of `fopen()` is usually the next free integer available. In the sample program above, you will mostly have a value of **`3`** contained in the file-descriptor `desc` as `0`, `1` & `2` are allotted by convention to `stdin`, `stdout` & `stderr`.

Answer (score 1):

First, this is a `FILE *` pointer, not a file descriptor. We refer file descriptor to the `int` to access files, sockets, etc. Foe example, `open` returns a file descriptor to access files, `socket` returns file descriptor to manipulate sockets.

And yes, it's safe because it doesn't point to a local object in the function.

Answer (score 1):

In this case it's safe because you aren't allocating a variable locally, you're allocating a pointer to a variable locally. The variable itself is living on the heap and is safe as long as you haven't closed/deallocated it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is yes. The memory fopen allocated for FILE type descriptor is in the heap, thus can be used out of the function.

As long as the FILE pointer is close by fclose only once after use, the whole code practice is safe by all means.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried it?

It should work without any problem

Scratch that

I will definitely work.

Comment: Trying it is not enough. If you have UB (and that is what the OP wonders about), it *might* succeed as well. (But in this case, it works.)

Comment: @glglgl - I was being a bit flippant. Seems a rather trivial question IMHO